# Can I change the extension of a StorageFile?

Tags: c#, uwp

My UWP app is a file converted. I have the user pick an input file using `FileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync()` and an output file using `FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()`.

From custom events I see that many users have files which are already in the correct internal format but have the wrong file extension, so just changing the name would be enough.

Can I do this through the `StorageFile` API?

Note: I know I can just copy over the contents to the output file, and I'm already doing so. I'm just wondering if it can be done more efficiently.

Comment: StorageFile.RenameAsync(...) should work, no?

Comment: I've seen that method, but couldn't find answers about (1) does it apply to extension too? (2) can it be used with permissions given by `FileOpenPicker`?

Comment: It applies to the extension as well.

Comment: The path returned by FileOpenPicker already includes the filename extension, no further help is necessary.  To allow the user to pick such a file, all you have to do is call FileTypeFilter.Add() to add extensions that you deem to be compatible

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. After testing with [`StorageFile.RenameAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.renameasync) as suggested in the comments, the following works:

```
string nextName = file.DisplayName + ".ext";
await file.RenameAsync(nextName, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName)
```

I was mainly worried since file picked through `FileOpenPicker` have many restriction, e.g. you cannot get the parent folder of the file, but renaming without collisions is not limited. I did not test however if `NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting` is let to overwrite existing files which were not picked.

Comment: I try to rename to .exe and it throws an exception.

Comment: What exception?

Comment: For UWP cant open or save any file to exe.